# MySQL order results by datetime and grouped by user ID

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have a table that looks like this:

| user_id | datetime | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-01-10 12:00:00 | Logout |
| 1 | 2022-01-09 12:00:00 | Login |
| 3 | 2022-01-08 12:00:00 | Login |
| 3 | 2022-01-07 12:00:00 | Register |
| 2 | 2022-01-06 12:00:00 | Login |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 12:00:00 | Register |

If I query the table sorted by `datetime DESC` I will get the result like the above.

How can I extend the query so that I can get the results grouped by the user_id like below?

| user_id | datetime | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-01-10 12:00:00 | Logout |
| 2 | 2022-01-06 12:00:00 | Login |
| 1 | 2022-01-09 12:00:00 | Login |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 12:00:00 | Register |
| 3 | 2022-01-08 12:00:00 | Login |
| 3 | 2022-01-07 12:00:00 | Register |

The logic is the records will be sorted by `datetime DESC` at first and when it encounters the user_id for the record, it will aggregate all records belonging to the user_id together and maintaining the `datetime DESC` sorting within the user_id group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX()` window function in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY MAX(datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) DESC,
         user_id, -- just in case there are duplicate datetimes, remove this if the column datetime is unique
         datetime DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8cjuQXzCjjnUF8xtwzb4RA/0).

Comment: That's phenomenal! Learnt something new today, thank you!